# How to apply the same background color expression to several columns based on different values

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

My client wants to apply conditional formatting to > 50 columns in my report, basically asking to color the cells orange if it is null/empty. The complexity comes from the condition also being based on the value of a different column.

For example, if my Program column = 'A', then all columns should be colored orange if a value is missing. But if my Program column = 'B', then only certain columns should be colored orange because the rest isn't required. I know how to use the IIf and IsNothing functions, but is there an easier way to apply a big expression to all columns - or another way to ask, how do I dynamically use IIF(IsNothing(Fields!**ColumnName**.Value), "Orange", "White") so that I don't have to manually change the column name for each of the 50+ cells?

I tried highlighting all the cells and changing the expression for Background Color, but I run into the issue of having to require a specific column name instead of a more dynamic approach.

Comment: Select all the cells and then change the property in the property pane instead.

Comment: Hi @ThomA what should I put in the Background color expression property to be able to apply that formula to all the selected columns?

Comment: I assume the expression you used above: `IIF(IsNothing(Fields!ColumnName.Value), "Orange", "White")`

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but I have to apply this to several columns, so if I have ColumnA and ColumnB, what do I replace for ColumnName in the function? Instead of clicking each column's cell and pasting the same expression over and over

Comment: That you can't do. The question read to me that you want all the columns to be based on the value of one column. You'll need to add the expression you need to each column instead. If you have 50 columns, that means repeating that 50 times.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of - thank you for confimring!

Comment: If you show a sample of your dataset (as text or a db fiddle) and a sample of the expected outcome, then there might be way of doing this, it all really depends on how simple your data is so I won't bother writing it all up it it's not going to work for you.

Comment: This is not best practice, however, if the query is being used only by your report, sometimes it is more efficient, and just easier, to put the logic in the stored procedure. For example, simply adding a derived CellColor column in your query may prove more efficient then adding 50 conditionals. BackgroundColor = Fields!CellColor.Value